# Function declaration vs lambdas

Tags: dart

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_function_declarations_over_variables.html

Is there any reason why local function declarations should be preferred over local final lambdas?

Performance? Lexical scope semantics?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any functioning difference between the two.

So, I would argue readability. There is no reason to introduce the extra lambda syntax when a simple function declaration achieves the same.

If you want a `Function var`, reassigning it to named functions will be more readable than reassigning it to unnamed lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Local functions are more readable.

1. They document the input and output types.  For example, you cannot explicitly specify a return type for a lambda, and the linter might complain about having [explicit parameter types on lambdas](http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_types_on_closure_parameters.html).
2. They look more like "normal" functions.